# Rails 3 with Postgresql - noisy db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3

I recently moved my Rails app to Postgres and noticed in the developments logs it's full of SQL statements like the following:

```
  SQL (1.1ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"permissions"'::regclass
 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum
  SQL (1.1ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"spaces"'::regclass
 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Anyone know what the deal is with this, seems like it's a performance hit? Is it?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797107/ruby-on-rails-active-record-generated-sql-on-postgres

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get rid of these messages with the [silent-postgres](http://railsonpostgresql.com/2010/10/06/reducing-log-output-from-the-rails-postgresql-connection-adapter) gem.